# Bootstrap- why won't my div jump to the next row on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 rows of content with 2 columns in each row, and this looks great on laptops. I tried to use bootstrap to line up the columns differently on mobile, so that each row only has one column instead of two. I know if the row has 2 divs in in and each div takes 12 sections, in theory the 2nd div will just to the row underneath but it's not working. For some reason, this isn't both columns are aligned next to each other and squished together instead of one being under the other. How do I get this to look better on mobile? Here is what one row looks like:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <a class="link-image" target="_blank" href=link>
      <div class="picture" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), url(some image);">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    <div class="description">
      <h4> <a href=link target="blank">link</a> </h4>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you made any CSS changes to bootstrap classes ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ukgrakL6/ your example seems to be working fine for me

Comment: Same as @Pat this seems to work just fine. Would you have some conflicting CSS that is affecting this?

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? If you're using bootstrap 4, you might try `col-12` instead of `col-xs-12` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Yes, changing the CSS fixed it, although now I have a different issue. I had display: flex in the div and a min height set to 90vh so that I can have a rather large div with the two items centered inside. When I remove the flex, they are no longer centered vertically and there's a lot of space on the bottom. When I remove min-height, the div they are centered but the box they are in is a lot smaller. How can I still have a large div and center the items inside it without flex?

Answer (score 2):

`-xs` is no longer used in Bootstrap 4.

Using correct V4 classes you would want to use `<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">...</div>`

Valid sizing for Grid is now:

```
.col-* 
.col-sm-*
.col-md-*
.col-lg-*
```

Per Bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system-1

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. It works. 
The reason you see only 1 row is that the 1st `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">` has no content, yet generate no height nor width.

Solution:

- just add content to the 1st `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">`, it will appear
- in case you want to leave it blank, set the attribute `min-height`.

I put some color in the sample for visual purpose.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="background-color: dodgerblue; min-height: 76px;">
            <a class="link-image" target="_blank" href=link>
                <div class="picture" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), url(some image);">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="background-color: coral;">
            <div class="description">
                <h4> <a href=link target="blank">link</a> </h4>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output (screenshot):

[image]